# Laravel blade @include view using variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a few blade template files which I want to include in my view dynamically based on the permissions of current user stored in session. Below is the code I've written:

```
@foreach (Config::get('constants.tiles') as $tile)
    @if (Session::get('currentUser')->get('permissions')[$tile]['read'] == 1)
        @include('dashboard.tiles.' . $tile)
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Blade is not allowing me to concatenate the constant string with the value of variable $tile. But I want to achieve this functionality. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: echo $tile & ensure that it is there. It should work fine if other things are ok.

Comment: Try `[{$tile}]` - does that fix it?

Comment: NOTE: @include('dashboard.tiles.' . $tile) works in Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can not concatenate string inside blade template command. So you can do assigning the included file name into a php variable and then pass it to blade template command.

```
@foreach (Config::get('constants.tiles') as $tile)
   @if (Session::get('currentUser')->get('permissions')[$tile]['read'] == 1)
     <?php $file_name = 'dashboard.tiles.' . $tile; ?>
     @include($file_name)
   @endif
@endforeach
```

*Laravel 5.4* - the dynamic includes with string concatenation works in blade templates

```
@foreach (Config::get('constants.tiles') as $tile)
   @if (Session::get('currentUser')->get('permissions')[$tile]['read'] == 1)
     @include('dashboard.tiles.' . $tile)
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yeah, I did the same but in Controller and then sent the view names as array in view.